# autohotkey: Run vba macro with ahk script

Tags: ms-word, autohotkey

```
    #Include Com.ahk            ; COM
        RunMSWordMacro(correct)
        {
            COM_Init()
            Word := COM_GetActiveObject("Word.Application")
            COM_Invoke(Word, "Run", "!"correct)
            COM_Release(Word)
            COM_Term()
        }

        ;    the hotkey is 1
    1::RunMSWordMacro("correct")
```

Why this code does not work? look at the picture "message", and help me
please, I'am new user in autohotkey.

When I press hotkey, it gave me this message:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebtDH.png]

this is my vba code:

Thanks David Metcalfe, that is my vba code:

```
Sub correct()
'
' correct Macro
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "p "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.TypeText Text:="o "
End Sub
```

Comment: You should ask a question. Posting code without telling us what is going wrong and what you are trying to do is almost useless. [Edit] your question and give us some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the help from here:
 [https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=37197&e=1&view=unread#unread][1]

```
   1:: RunMSWordMacro("correct")

    RunMSWordMacro(name)  {
       GetWord().Run(name)
    }

    GetWord()  {
       if !hwnd := WinActive("ahk_class OpusApp")
          hwnd := WinExist("ahk_class OpusApp")
       ControlGet, ControlHwnd, Hwnd,, _WwG1, ahk_id %hwnd%
       Return AccObjectFromWindow(ControlHwnd, -16).Application
    }

    AccObjectFromWindow(hWnd, idObject = 0)
    {
       static IID_IDispatch   := "{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"
            , IID_IAccessible := "{618736e0-3c3d-11cf-810c-00aa00389b71}"
            , OBJID_NATIVEOM := 0xFFFFFFF0, VT_DISPATCH := 9, h := DllCall("LoadLibrary", Str, "oleacc", Ptr)

       VarSetCapacity(IID, 16), idObject &= 0xFFFFFFFF
       DllCall("ole32\CLSIDFromString", Str, idObject = OBJID_NATIVEOM ? IID_IDispatch : IID_IAccessible, Ptr, &IID)
       if DllCall("oleacc\AccessibleObjectFromWindow", Ptr, hWnd, UInt, idObject, Ptr, &IID, PtrP, pAcc) = 0
          Return ComObjEnwrap(VT_DISPATCH, pAcc, 1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you explained what the end goal of your code is. Based on the VBA you've provided, it seems you're just trying to run Microsoft Word, in which case you could use AutoHotkey entirely.

The [Run](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) syntax is quite simple to use.

```
Run, C:\Path\to\Microsoft Word.exe
```

Comment: I do not just want to run Microsoft Word, I  sent a vba code and I want to run it using AHK, please help.

Comment: @asad41163 Your supplied code doesn't do any better a job of illustrating at its core what you're trying to accomplish. All you're telling us is that you want to run VBA code via AHK, but you're not getting at the 'why'. Often times the end goal can be accomplished through far better means and we get too fixated on a singular solution.

Comment: First, please excuse me not to master the language
Second, The VBA Code mentioned in the example above is just a very simple example, and I am working on correcting the books on the Word program and I need very much of the macro, provided that the macro is run by a single hotkey, such as a::, b::, t::, and so on.
So I want to take advantage of the various possibilities of the Word program in search and replace, and benefit from the Autohotkey in the single key.
Please help me

Comment: @asad41163 If you want to find and replace, that's as simple as F5, Alt+P. Or `SendInput, {F5}!P`.

Comment: I am sorry, the solution: [link](https://autohotkey.com:443/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=37197&e=1&view=unread#unread)

Comment: @asad41163 "You have been notified about this topic, please login to view it." I guess I'll just take your word for it then.